When the TipKit notification popovers, ignore the tip, the 'present sheet' button will be non-functional. (iPhone SE and simulator devices)
import SwiftUI
import TipKit

@main
struct TipKit_WithPresentPageApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .task {
                    try? Tips.resetDatastore()
                    try? Tips.configure([
                        .datastoreLocation(.applicationDefault)
                    ])
                }
        }
    }
}

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundStyle(.tint)
                    .popoverTip(MyTip())
                    .padding(100)
                Button("Hit Me!") {
                    isPresented.toggle()
                    // When the TipKit notification appears, the 'present sheet' button will be non-functional. (iPhone SE and simulator devices)
                }
                .padding()
                .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                    PresentPage()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

import SwiftUI

struct PresentPage: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world again!")
            .font(.title)
    }
}

import TipKit

struct MyTip: Tip {
    var title: Text {
        Text("Test")
    }
    var message: Text? {
        Text("Hi")
    }
}

When the TipKit notification appears, the 'present sheet' button will be non-functional. (iPhoneSE Landscape Right)
When using the iPhone SE (Landscape Right) or its simulator (iPhone SE Landscape Right), running iOS 17.2. Whenever the TipKit notification is triggered and displayed on the screen, the 'present sheet' button, which is typically used for presenting a new sheet within the app, becomes non-functional.
Device: iPhoneSE iOS 17.2
enter image description here
Does anyone know how to bypass this bug？ Thank you.

I have had the same issue.
I fixed it by adding a small delay in the button action
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundStyle(.tint)
                    .popoverTip(MyTip())
                    .padding(100)
                Button("Hit Me!") {
                    // HERE 
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                        isPresented.toggle()
                    }
                    // HERE
                }
                .padding()
                .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                    PresentPage()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Edit:
I have found that this only works sometimes. I have found here a solution that always works, but might not be applicable in all scenarios.
           Button("Hit Me!") {
                yourtip.invalidate(reason: .actionPerformed)
                isPresented.toggle()
            }

